# Как можно вывести массив времени?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Нужно вывести массив времени с 9:00 до 00:00
что-то типо этого

```
<% ((9:00)..(23:00)).map do |date| %>
   <%= date %>
<% end %>
```

Можно ли это как-то сделать?

Comment: Я думаю массив таки нужно вывести для javascript, а значит нужно сделать join по запятой и добавить `[]`... , преобразовать всёравно в строку, а потом вывести.

Comment: При использовании шага в 1 секунду, 1 минуту и 1 час получатся массивы разительно разных размеров. А ещё в вышеприведённом примере `map` не нужен, достаточно `each`. Разницы в поведении не будет никакой, зато лишняя память копиться не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Литералы такого вида не предусмотрены.

В зависимости от того, какой шаг вам нужен...

- ...если час, то можно получить сразу нужное представление (и его, если надо, превратить в объекты `Time`):

  ```
  (9..23).map { |h| "#{h}:00" }
  ```
- ...с любым шагом (и получая объекты `Time`):

  ```
  (Time.parse('9:00').to_i..Time.parse('23:00').to_i).step(3600) # в секундах
                                                     .map { |ts| Time.at(ts) }
  ```

  ...а с ActiveSupport даже почти красиво:

  ```
  (Time.parse('9:00').to_i..Time.parse('23:00').to_i).step(1.hour)
                                                     .map { |ts| Time.at(ts) }
  ```

Обратите внимание, что в Ruby класс `Time` работает только с конкретными моментами, не просто "значениями на часах", а привязанными к дате. Когда дата не указана, `.parse` предполагает сегодняшний день. Но при преобразовании в строки дату можно и опустить.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает как надо!